# Firebase Web: Method doesn't trigger first time inside of child_added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat functionality in my project. When someone is sending a message I update the database using push.

And I define a method called renderChatUI.

I define a listener like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(`USERS/${Database.getNestedData('UID')}/UserClass/${grade}/${subject}/Topics/${key}/Chats`).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  console.log('Hello');
  this.renderChatUI(UID, grade, subject, key);
})
```

So that, every time any message is added to this path, my chat UI re-renders.

The child_added block of code executes perfectly, but the renderChatUI() method doesn't trigger the first time (when I add first message). When adding second message, chat UI re-renders with first Message, when adding third chat UI re-renders with second and so on...!

I can't figure out whats going wrong. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow the `child-added` to trigger after adding to the database, then you can use a completion callback, for example:

```
 firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      // The write failed...
    } else {
      // Data saved successfully!
      firebase.database().ref(`USERS/${Database.getNestedData('UID')}/UserClass/${grade}/${subject}/Topics/${key}/Chats`).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
         console.log('Hello');
         this.renderChatUI(UID, grade, subject, key);
       })
    }
  });
}
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback):

> The optional completion callback that is called when the write has been committed to the database. If the call was unsuccessful, the callback is passed an error object indicating why the failure occurred.

Comment: Figure out, on block of code execute before pushing data to database. So UI render with previous data. setTimeout() can solve the issue, but in initial load 'on' block of code trigger once for every child. That means - if i set timeout 10ms and i have 1k message, on first load it takes 10s ! 
value-event doesn't work for my case. It calls every time when page re-load !

Comment: u can use `once('value')` which gets called once `.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {...}`

Comment: But i need to update ui every time when new child(message) added, As far i know once invoke one time.

Comment: ohh i understand

Comment: @Robin check my edit to the answer, instead of `setTimout` use completion callback same as in the answer.

Comment: Is it necessary define listener like on('child_added) in every successful case ? Whether i put listener block of code, it will invoke when child added into that path. I don't think its useful.

Comment: @Robin it is necessary if the data you are retrieving depends on the data your are adding. If you are adding under node `users` and retrieving from node `admin`, then retrieving data doesnt depend on `push()`, so you can add it in another place

Comment: When new message is added, i compare the store with database, And return the new message as snapshot using callback. Then update the UI. Some asynchronous execution is happening here, so i need to handle it. I am going to use promise, so that i can handle execution. Thanks for your response, helpful discussion.